# How Do I Save What I have Drawn In A CGContext

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have drawn into a CGContext of a UIView.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    [self drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]  
}
```

I would like to save what I have drawn to a png file.

Is there a simple solution?

EDIT: Based on suggestions below - here's what I have so far....

```
-(void)createImage {
    NSString* outFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.png"];
    DLog(@"creating image file at %@", outFile);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:outFile 
                atomically:NO];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    [self drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
    [self createImage];
}
```

Comment: maybe a better thing to ask for is how to create a bitmap context and replay my drawings into that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:@"image.png" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I must be missing something simple. I do this within the drawRect call. Running on the iPhone simulator - i don't see any file created.

Comment: You may have to specify the complete path to the Documents directory instead of just image.png.

Comment: I updated my example code above - but no file is created in the emulator. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: My `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` kept returning `nil`, may have better luck using the answer below

Answer (score 7):

```
CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```

Comment: Don't just post code as an answer, try to give it some explanation as to why this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` to get an UIImage.
Then call `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to get an NSData of the UIImage encoded in PNG.
Finally, call `-writeToFile:…` to save the NSData.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let imageWidth = inputCGImage.width
let imageHeight = inputCGImage.height

let imageRect = NSRect(
    origin: .zero,
    size: CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)
)

context.draw(inputCGImage, in: imageRect)

let outputImageRef = context.makeImage()!

let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]

let destinationURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: paths.first!).appendingPathComponent("output.png")!

guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(destinationURL as CFURL, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil) else {
    throw HoleFillingError.CoreGraphicsError
}

CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, outputImageRef, nil)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
```