# How do you draw to a CGContextRef and save as png?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've got a void that draws to a given CGContextRef that is usually supplied in the drawRect routine of a custom view however I also need to generate a CGContextRef that it can draw to that would allow me to save the resulting image as a PNG file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Save What I have Drawn In A CGContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568421/how-do-i-save-what-i-have-drawn-in-a-cgcontext)

Comment: @Danich nope, this is about OSX, not iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty simple:

```
NSImage *toSave = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(600, 900)];

[toSave lockFocus];

CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

//drawing code

[toSave unlockFocus];

NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = [[toSave representations] objectAtIndex: 0];

NSData *data = [imgRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];

[data writeToFile: @"/path/to/file.png" atomically: NO];
```

Comment: This crashed on me (os x Yosemite, Xcode 6). Luckily I found cobbal's answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223739/ios-to-mac-graphiccontext-explanation-conversion