# iOS to Mac GraphicContext Explanation/Conversion

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, converters, cgcontext

I have been programming for two years on iOS and never on mac. I am working on a little utility for handling some simple image needs that I have in my iOS development. Anyway, I have working code in iOS that runs perfectly but I have absolutely no idea what equivalents are for mac.

I've tried a bunch of different things but I really don't understand how to start a graphics context on the Mac outside of a "drawRect:" method. On the iPhone I would just use UIGraphicsBeghinImageContext(). I know other post have said to use lockFocus/unlockFocus but I'm not sure how exactly to make that work for my needs. Oh, and I really miss UIImage's "CGImage" property. I don't understand why NSImage can't have one, though it sounds a bit trickier than just that.

Here is my working code on iOS—basically it just creates a reflected image from a mask and combines them together:

```
    UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Mask_Image.jpg" ofType:nil]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed::@"Test_Image1.jpg"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mask.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, mask.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.f, -1.f);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, -mask.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    UIImage *flippedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef maskRef = mask.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskCreate = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                              CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([flippedImage CGImage], maskCreate);

    CGImageRelease(maskCreate);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height + (image.size.height * .5)), NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [maskedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, image.size.height, maskedImage.size.width, maskedImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *anotherImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

//do something with anotherImage
```

Any suggestions for achieving this (simply) on the Mac?

Comment: Simple: `(CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]`

Comment: Does that start a graphics context? If so, how do I then draw the image(s) into it and retrieve them (like UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()). Also, how am I going to go between an NSImage and CGImage?

Comment: Added a Swift version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34361216/1226095

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a simple example that draws a blue circle into an NSImage (I'm using ARC in this example, add retains/releases to taste)

```
NSSize size = NSMakeSize(50, 50);

NSImage* im = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:size];
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                            initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                          pixelsWide:size.width
                                          pixelsHigh:size.height
                                       bitsPerSample:8
                                     samplesPerPixel:4
                                            hasAlpha:YES
                                            isPlanar:NO
                                      colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                         bytesPerRow:0
                                        bitsPerPixel:0];

[im addRepresentation:rep];

[im lockFocus];

CGContextRef ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextClearRect(ctx, NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[NSColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

[im unlockFocus];

[[im TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:@"/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/foo.tiff" atomically:NO];
```

The main difference is that on OS X you first have to create the image, then you can begin drawing into it; on iOS you create the context, then extract the image from it.

Basically, lockFocus makes the current context be the image and you draw directly onto it, then use the image.

I'm not completely sure if this answers all of your question, but I think it's at least one part of it.

Comment: So I kind of figured that was what locking the focus does, but how would I do something like flipping the image? I have attempted to flip the context and then draw the image in it but the image always comes out right side up. Another thing, is TIFF the only format I can save out to?

Comment: God bless you, @cobbal!

Answer (score 10):

Well, here's the note on `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`:

> **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**
>
> > *Creates a bitmap-based graphics context with the specified options.*

The OS X equivalent, which is also available in iOS (and `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is possibly a wrapper around) is `CGBitmapContextCreate`:

Declared as:

```
CGContextRef CGBitmapContextCreate (
   void *data,
   size_t width,
   size_t height,
   size_t bitsPerComponent,
   size_t bytesPerRow,
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo
);
```

Although it's a C API, you could think of CGBitmapContext as a subclass of CGContext. It renders to a pixel buffer, whereas a CGContext renders to an abstract destination.

For `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, you can use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` and pass your bitmap context to create a CGImage.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a Swift (2.1 / 10.11 API-compliant) version of [Cobbal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270398/1226095)

```
    let size = NSMakeSize(50, 50);
    let im = NSImage.init(size: size)

    let rep = NSBitmapImageRep.init(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
        pixelsWide: Int(size.width),
        pixelsHigh: Int(size.height),
        bitsPerSample: 8,
        samplesPerPixel: 4,
        hasAlpha: true,
        isPlanar: false,
        colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace,
        bytesPerRow: 0,
        bitsPerPixel: 0)

    im.addRepresentation(rep!)
    im.lockFocus()

    let rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext
    CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, NSColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect)

    im.unlockFocus()
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift3 version of [Cobbal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223739/ios-to-mac-graphiccontext-explanation-conversion/12270398#12270398)

```
   let size = NSMakeSize(50, 50);
    let im = NSImage.init(size: size)

    let rep = NSBitmapImageRep.init(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
                                    pixelsWide: Int(size.width),
                                    pixelsHigh: Int(size.height),
                                    bitsPerSample: 8,
                                    samplesPerPixel: 4,
                                    hasAlpha: true,
                                    isPlanar: false,
                                    colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace,
                                    bytesPerRow: 0,
                                    bitsPerPixel: 0)


   im.addRepresentation(rep!)
    im.lockFocus()

    let rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext
    ctx!.clear(rect)
    ctx!.setFillColor(NSColor.black.cgColor)
    ctx!.fill(rect)

    im.unlockFocus()
```